# save / update a (Moped) BSON::Document with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, moped

I tried many ways to update an existing bson document, but it never changes in my mongodb:

```
col = db["collection"]
col.insert({"ben": 1})
doc = col.find().to_a.first
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('556c7f1b167e70640070a4d9'), "ben"=>1}
```

first attempt to update:

```
doc.merge!({"ben": 5, "ams": 6})
col.find().to_a.first
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('556c7f1b167e70640070a4d9'), "ben"=>1}
```

second attempt to update:

```
doc.update({"ben": 5, "ams": 6})
col.find().to_a.first
# => {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('556c7f1b167e70640070a4d9'), "ben"=>1}
```

third attempt...

```
doc["ben"] = 5
doc["ams"] = 6
doc.save
# NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<BSON::Document:0x00000003f284d0>
```

As you can see, none of the above works for me. I couldn't find any other suggestions by a google search. Do yo know ways to update my document? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you do this:

```
col.find().to_a
#          ^^^^
```

you're working with a simple array of Ruby hashes that have no connection to the database. So when you say:

```
doc.update({"ben": 5, "ams": 6})
```

you're calling [`Hash#update`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-update). If you want to update something, you'd call [`update`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query#update-instance_method) on what [`find`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Collection#find-instance_method) returns:

```
col.find.update(:$set => { 'ben' => 5, 'ams' => 6 })
```

or if you want to replace the entire document:

```
col.find.update('ben' => 5, 'ams' => 6)
```

You'd usually tell `find` which specific document you want of course.

Note that `update` only updates the first matching document it finds, if you want to update all matching documents then you'd use [`update_all`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query#update_all-instance_method).

Comment: Hi, your point is very clear. Thanks! 
Does it mean that I can't update documents during iteration? (For example: `col.find().each { |d| d.update("ben": 5, "ams": 6) }`)

Comment: Right, that won't work because `d` will just be a simple Hash inside the `each` block. You'd need to `col.find(:_id => ...).update(...)` inside the iteration. Normally you'd use Mongoid instances to take care of all this, Moped is usually only used when you want to talk directly to the database.